# Simple Ada program with wrong output

Tags: compilation, ada, gnat

Complete beginner to Ada here.
I am trying to compile and run a simple Ada program, from here: http://www.dwheeler.com/lovelace/s1sf.htm

Here is the code:

```
-- Demonstrate a trivial procedure, with another nested inside.
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Compute is

 procedure Double(Item : in out Integer) is
 begin -- procedure Double.
   Item := Item * 2;
 end Double;

 X : Integer := 1;   -- Local variable X of type Integer.

begin -- procedure Compute
 loop
  Put(X);
  New_Line;
  Double(X);
 end loop;
end Compute;
```

I'm on Linux, using gnat so I do:

```
gnatmake -c compute.adb
gnatmake compute
```

Which gives me the executable. Running the executable gives a list of zeros, as it seems to initialize X to 0, even though it says to initialize it to 1, so I *should* get a list 1,2,4,...

Can anyone explain either where my code or my thinking is wrong? Oh and using gnat is there a way to compile and create the executable in a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess that when you added "-gnato", gnatmake simply replied `gnatmake: "compute" up to date.` leaving you with the same executable.

```
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$ gnatmake -gnato compute.adb
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$ ./compute
          1
          2
...
  536870912
 1073741824
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : compute.adb:9 overflow check failed
```

Then without -gnato (I had to touch the source or I got the "up to date" message)

```
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$ gnatmake compute.adb
brian@Gannet:~/Ada/Play$ ./compute
          1
          2
...
  536870912
 1073741824
-2147483648
          0
          0
          0
          0
```

which subsequently appears as a string of zeroes. Adding your extra "if" statement touched the file, forcing recompilation : the "if" itself is not strictly necessary (though testing and preventing constraint error is a Good Thing!)

The moral : without -gnato, or rather, without at least the flags `-gnataoE -fstack_check`, Gnat is not an Ada compiler.

Comment: You can use the `-f` flag to `gnatmake` to force a complete recompile/rebuild.

Comment: "Gnat is not an Ada compiler" is putting it more strongly than we have to. Maybe "not fully Standard-compliant" would give less ammunition to the ungodly! Also, adding `-gnatE` loses you one of the more user-friendly aspects of GNAT, with very little benefit.

Comment: ok, perhaps we need a canonical statement of the minimum Ada compliant flag set. I'm sure I saw one somewhere - perhaps several, all different. As for "not an Ada compiler" in may be too strong, but the OP's observed program behaviour is not up to the standard I look to Ada for, and through no fault of his own.

Comment: The best I can find offhand is http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GNAT which supports your observation but suggests -gnata is also unnecessary

Comment: HAH! re: the gnatE switch, I had been aiming for gnateE and missed! This is an optional switch producing extra info on exceptions, which I found eerily accurate in post-mortem diagnostics.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gcc.html

Answer (score 0):

As you double the integer value each time without any delay in the loop, it will overflow quickly. In GNAT, overflow checking is off by default, you can enable it with the `-gnato` switch. So when the integer value overflows, it finally gets 0 and that's what you're seeing (the output is too fast to see the initial numbers).

Compiling with `-gnato` should give you a constraint error on execution. You can also produce the executable with one line by executing

```
gnatmake -gnato compute.adb
```

Comment: I used -gnato but still end up with a long list of zeros (after overgrowing Integer). I added an if statement in compute procedure and now it works (i.e. if X<20000 then...)

Comment: Indeed, the [Ada Reference Manual](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-5.html) doesn't state that signed integer multiplication does trigger a constraint error. It just says that _Signed integer multiplication has its conventional meaning_. So that's probably why you don't get a constraint error. Perhaps someone else can elaborate on this.

Comment: I don't think this is an Ada Reference Manual issue. Regardless what the multiplication does, the assignment to Item must raise Constraint Error for out-of-range values.

Comment: You're right, it's the assignment that should raise the error. I was a bit confused because the ARM mentions Constraint_Error for division, but not for multiplication, but that's another thing.